# Set two compound drawables in Android EditText

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-textinputlayout

I have the below `TextInputEditTexts` nested inside custom `TextInputLayouts` and I'm wanting to have both the "x" icon and the password toggle visible at the same time. However, the eye toggle is overriding the "x" icon.

I have a custom `TextInputLayout` called `LoginInputLayout` where I'm trying to add two drawables over on the right hand side of the password editText, but I keep only getting the eye icon.

**How can I add the two drawables over on the right hand side and not have one override the other? Like in the image below.**

This is the design that I'm trying to get to

[image]

In the Android implementation for the parent `LayoutInputTextView` it looks like the first child is actually a `FrameLayout` and a child of that FL is the `TextInputEditText`.

When the password toggle (which causes the eye to appear) is set to show, it looks like the android implementation inflates the view for the toggle, and sets it inside the FrameLayout like below.

```
if (shouldShowPasswordIcon()) {
            if (mPasswordToggleView == null) {
                mPasswordToggleView = (CheckableImageButton) LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.design_text_input_password_icon, mInputFrame, false);
                mPasswordToggleView.setImageDrawable(mPasswordToggleDrawable);
                mPasswordToggleView.setContentDescription(mPasswordToggleContentDesc);
                mInputFrame.addView(mPasswordToggleView);

                mPasswordToggleView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        passwordVisibilityToggleRequested(false);
                    }
                });
            }
```

The only thing is, the mFrameLayout member variable is private and I can't add more children in there or control where they're placed. Which is why I feel like I'm limited to trying the compound drawable way.

```
 <com.ge.cbyge.view.LoginInputTextLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        app:error="@{viewModel.emailError}">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/login_fragment_email_text"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@={viewModel.email}"/>

    </com.ge.cbyge.view.LoginInputTextLayout>

    <com.ge.cbyge.view.LoginInputTextLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/placeholder_dimen"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:error="@{viewModel.passwordError}"
        app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/password_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/login_fragment_password_text"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:text="@={viewModel.password}"/>

</com.ge.cbyge.view.LoginInputTextLayout>
```

This is my custom implementation of the `TextInputLayout`

```
class LoginInputTextLayout : TextInputLayout, TextWatcher {

    lateinit var clearTextIcon: Drawable

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle)

    override fun addView(child: View?, index: Int, params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams) {
        super.addView(child, index, params)

        if(child is EditText) {
            Timber.d("$TAG child was an editText")
            if (editText != null) {
                Timber.d("$TAG initializing the clearText")
                init(context)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun init(context: Context) {
        val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_material)
        DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, editText!!.currentHintTextColor)
        clearTextIcon = drawable
        clearTextIcon.setBounds(0, 0, clearTextIcon.intrinsicHeight, clearTextIcon.intrinsicHeight)
        setClearIconVisible(false)
        editText!!.transformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()
        editText!!.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener)
        editText!!.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusChangeListener)
        editText!!.addTextChangedListener(this)
    }

    private val onTouchListener: View.OnTouchListener = OnTouchListener { v, event ->
        val x = event.x.toInt()
        if (clearTextIcon.isVisible && x > width - paddingRight - clearTextIcon.intrinsicWidth) {
            if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                editText?.setText("")
            }
            return@OnTouchListener true
        }

        return@OnTouchListener false
    }

    private val focusChangeListener: View.OnFocusChangeListener = OnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            setClearIconVisible(editText!!.text.isNotEmpty())
        } else {
            setClearIconVisible(false)
        }
    }

    private fun setClearIconVisible(visible: Boolean) {
        clearTextIcon.setVisible(visible, false)
        val compoundDrawables = TextViewCompat.getCompoundDrawablesRelative(editText!!)
        TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawablesRelative(
                editText!!,
                compoundDrawables[0],
                compoundDrawables[1],
                if (visible) clearTextIcon else null,
                compoundDrawables[3])
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        if (editText!!.isFocused) {
            setClearIconVisible(s.isNotEmpty())
        }
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}
}
```

Comment: Consider giving up as not worth the effort. Users can delete their text using their keyboards just fine. If you really really need this (do you?) maybe just put this view inside another view and manually add your x on top. It'll be gross and hard to position correctly, though.

Comment: @AutonomousApps check out my solution. Designer wants it  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. went more or less the route you touched on though.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this to work, straying away from the composite disposable right. I was able to snag the `FrameLayout` in the `addView()` method, detect if it had two children (meaning the editText AND the eye logo) and if it did, set the "x" marker to the left of the eye.

```
class LoginInputTextLayout : TextInputLayout, TextWatcher {

    private lateinit var clearTextIcon: ImageView
    private lateinit var frameLayout: FrameLayout

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle)

    override fun addView(child: View?, index: Int, params: ViewGroup.LayoutParams) {
        super.addView(child, index, params)

        if (child is FrameLayout) {
            frameLayout = child
        }

        if(child is EditText) {
            if (editText != null) {
                init()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun init() {
        initClearTextIcon(isPasswordVisibilityToggleEnabled)
        editText!!.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusChangeListener)
        editText!!.addTextChangedListener(this)
    }

    private fun initClearTextIcon(passwordToggleEnabled: Boolean) {
        val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_material)
        DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, editText!!.currentHintTextColor)

        clearTextIcon = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.design_text_input_password_icon, frameLayout, false) as ImageView
        clearTextIcon.maxHeight = editText!!.height
        clearTextIcon.setImageDrawable(drawable)
        clearTextIcon.setOnClickListener {
            editText?.setText("")
        }

        if (passwordToggleEnabled) {
            val shiftedClearTextIcon = clearTextIcon
            shiftedClearTextIcon.setPadding(0,0, passwordVisibilityToggleDrawable!!.intrinsicWidth * 2, 0)
            frameLayout.addView(clearTextIcon)
            editText!!.transformationMethod = PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance()
        } else {
            frameLayout.addView(clearTextIcon)
        }
        setClearIconVisible(false)
    }

    private val focusChangeListener: View.OnFocusChangeListener = OnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
        if (hasFocus) {
            setClearIconVisible(editText!!.text.isNotEmpty())
        } else {
            setClearIconVisible(false)
        }
    }

    private fun setClearIconVisible(visible: Boolean) {
        if (visible) clearTextIcon.visibility = View.VISIBLE else clearTextIcon.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        if (editText!!.isFocused) {
            setClearIconVisible(s.isNotEmpty())
        }
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}
}
```